# What is the difference between train, test, validation and ensembled data, blended data, and test data?

Tags: r, machine-learning, ensemble-learning, train-test-split

Help me understand the difference between these two snippets

1)

```
set.seed(123)
ss <- sample(1:3,size=nrow(dataframe),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.6,0.2,0.2))
train <- mtcars[ss==1,]
test <- mtcars[ss==2,]
cvr <- mtcars[ss==3,]
```

When I try ensemble method

2)

```
# shuffle and split the data into three parts
set.seed(1234)
finaltrain <- finaltrain[sample(nrow(finaltrain)),]
split <- floor(nrow(finaltrain)/3)
ensembleData <- finaltrain[0:split,]
blenderData <- finaltrain[(split+1):(split*2),]
testingData <- finaltrain[(split*2+1):nrow(finaltrain),]
```

My question is when ensembling what is it that I am doing differently? I am beginner help me understand this.

Comment: The two snippets are just different ways to randomly partition data into 3 parts. The first snippet is aiming for a 60-20-20 split and the second is aiming for roughly equal partitions.

Comment: @astrofunkswag So there is no difference and it's just about naming conventions right?

Comment: The code snippets are substantively different in a couple ways.

The second snippet guarantees an equal 1/3 split of the data, with at most size `n = 1` difference between the groups due to rounding

The first randomizes the group sizes, so you are not guaranteed the 60-20-20 data split

Answer (score 1):

**Training dataset**
used to be similar to the model, the dataset used to train the model (the weight is also biased in the case of the neural network)
then the learning model of this data.

usually the training dataset is inserted in .csv or .txt format if the programming language you are using is python.
and you can also use the form matrix for the dataset but the changes in coding should be changed one by one.

**Validation dataset**
sample data used for unbiased evaluation of a suitable model on the training dataset.
set validation is used to evaluate the given model.

**Test the dataset**
what test sets are generally used to evaluate competing models.
for example such as determining the winner in the Kaggle competition, the validation set is released simultaneously with the training set and the test set is actually only released when the competition is over.
and that's the result of the model on the test set to decide the winner.
// test sets are usually filled with carefully collected data covering the various classes that the model will encounter.